# KEDA kafka - azure eventhub configuration

Tags: azure, kubernetes, apache-kafka, keda, eventhub

I am having trouble when configuring ScaledObject for a kafka cluster although I've read de documentation I can't seem to understand why this isn't working I think I'm misconfiguring the appropiate scaled object.

I have configured a kafka trigger but this hasn't been working so instead I had tried to use a azure-eventhub one but don't know if this is the correct approach.

Having an issue when trying to configure a keda kafka scaled object with my triggerAuthentication I was trying to configure a plaintext authentication on kafka using the eventhub connection string as password like this:

ScaledObject.yaml

YAML

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: scaled-object-name
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: app-name
  pollingInterval: 30
  triggers:
    - type: kafka
      metadata:
        bootstrapServers: <bootstrap-servers>
        consumerGroup: <consumer-group>     # This consumer group name has to be the one is consuming topics
        topic: <topic-name>
        tls: disable
        sasl: plaintext
        # Optional
        lagThreshold: "50"
        offsetResetPolicy: latest
      authenticationRef:
        name: keda-trigger-auth-kafka-credential
```

kafka-keda-secret

YAML

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: kafka-auth-secret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  username: "$ConnectionString"
  password: "Endpoint=sb://{namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={policy-name};SharedAccessKey={policy-key}"
```

TriggerAuthentication

YAML

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: keda-trigger-auth-kafka-credential
spec:
  secretTargetRef:
    - parameter: username
      name: keda-kafka-secrets
      key: username
    - parameter: password
      name: keda-kafka-secrets
      key: password
```

But I wasn't able to it throws this error

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                 From           Message
  ----     ------                   ----                ----           -------
  Warning  KEDAScalerFailed         14m (x99 over 22h)  keda-operator  error parsing kafka metadata: no username given
  Warning  ScaledObjectCheckFailed  14m (x99 over 22h)  keda-operator  failed to ensure HPA is correctly created for ScaledObject
```

So instead I'm trying to configure an azure-eventhub ScaledObject like this

ScaledObjectAZEH

```
YAML
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: scaled-object-az-eh
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: app-name
  pollingInterval: 30
  triggers:
    - type: azure-eventhub
      metadata:
        eventHubInfo:
          connectionStringFromEnv: EVENTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING
        consumerGroup: $Default
        partitionCount: 2
        storageConnectionFromEnv: ""
```

Do you have any recomendation on how to configure KEDA on kafka or azure eventhub?

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: I have solved my issue with keda and eventhub/kafka implementation I had misconfigured the ScaledObject.yaml

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue by finding a misconfiguration on my ScaledObject

ScaledObject.yaml

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: scaled-object-name
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: app-name
  pollingInterval: 30
  triggers:
    - type: kafka
      metadata:
        bootstrapServers: <bootstrap-servers>
        consumerGroup: <consumer-group>     # This consumer group name has to be the one is consuming topics
        topic: <topic-name>
        # Optional
        lagThreshold: "50"
        offsetResetPolicy: latest
      authenticationRef:
        name: keda-trigger-auth-kafka-credential
```

TriggerAuthentication.yaml

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: keda-trigger-auth-kafka-credential
spec:
  secretTargetRef:
    - parameter: username
      name: keda-kafka-secrets
      key: username
    - parameter: password
      name: keda-kafka-secrets
      key: password
    - parameter: sasl
      name: keda-kafka-secrets
      key: sasl
    - parameter: tls
      name: keda-kafka-secrets
      key: tls
```

Secrets.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: kafka-auth-secret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  tls: "enable"
  sasl: "plaintext"
  username: <username>
  password: <azure-evnthub-connection-string>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**